# Xcode 4.2, Three20 on iOS 3.0 Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UISplitViewController

Tags: xcode, three20, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using Xcode 4.2 and Three20 to create app that can be run on all iOS.

When I run the app on iPhone 3G having iOS 3.0,
I see a crash with the following message in the Debug Console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/7AB01877-55F2-4A5F-A835-FF7849D6E285/Xcode4M.app/Xcode4M
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

I followed this [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001374/symbol-not-found-objc-class-uipopovercontroller) and fix the crash.
Now I receive another crash with this message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UISplitViewController
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/7AB01877-55F2-4A5F-A835-FF7849D6E285/Xcode4M.app/Xcode4M
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

I tried to fix this crash with the same method, but not succeeded.

Do you know how to fix this?

**Edit**: (Add problematic code)

File: **TTSplitViewController**

```
@interface TTSplitViewController : UISplitViewController 
<UISplitViewControllerDelegate, TTNavigatorRootContainer> {
@private
  TTNavigator* _leftNavigator;
  TTNavigator* _rightNavigator;
  UIBarButtonItem*      _splitViewButton;
  id  _popoverSplitController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you can see the code in the pull request at https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/695/files. It solves all 3.1 issues, besides the TTSplitViewController.

it uses a special function of three20 to create a UIPopViewController

```
_popoverController =  [[TTUIPopoverControllerClass() alloc] init];
  if (_popoverController != nil) {
    [_popoverController setContentViewController:controller];
    [_popoverController setDelegate:self];
  }
```

You will still need to comment out TTSplitViewController, however that's the only class that has an issue with iOS 3.1. (see the comments in the pull request)

Answer (score 0):

I uncheck **TTSplitViewController.h** and **TTSplitViewController.m** in the Target Membership.
and comment the line

```
//#import "Three20UI/TTSplitViewController.h"
```

in **Three20UI.h**

[image]

and uncheck **UISplitViewController+TTNavigator.h** and **UISplitViewController+TTNavigator.m** from their Target Membership.

and comment the line

```
//#import "Three20UICommon/UISplitViewController+TTNavigator.h"
```

in **Three20UICommon+Additions.h**

[image]

I works, but I would prefer to do something like [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001374/symbol-not-found-objc-class-uipopovercontroller) so I can use these classes later. I'd be glad if someone know how to do it.